# I get problems creating a collection in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, collections

In the VBA Editor, I have created a new collection of worksheets with the following code:

```
Set Page1s = New Collection
Page1s.Add Workbook010.Sheets("1stPage")
```

For now, I've got only one worksheet in this collection that I'd like to copy with the following code

```
Workbook010.Page1s(1).Copy After:=Sheets("1stPage")
```

The here above line of code generate a Run-Time Error 9, Subscript out of Range...
I don't understand why can't I reach the first item of the collection that I have just created?
I thank you very much in advance for your feedback.
Franz

Answer (score 1):

You are **over-specifying** the object being copied.  This will work just fine:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim Workbook010 As Workbook
    Set Workbook010 = ThisWorkbook
    Set Page1s = New Collection

    Page1s.Add Workbook010.Sheets("1stPage")
    Page1s(1).Copy After:=Sheets("1stPage")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary's Student !